# How to identify a button using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bW0J5.png)This is a screenshot of the element (`button`) I am trying to identify:

[image]

How can I identify the button using Selenium Webdriver?

Comment: have a look at the locators that selenium has https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp https://www.protechtraining.com/bookshelf/selenium_tutorial/locators?ncr=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following xpath for your case:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Add Criteria')]")).click();
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: thanks ..it is identifying the element but click is not working, unable to click on this.same error message appears .

Answer (score 0):

```
//a[contains(.,'Add Criteria')]
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.can u please send complete command. I tried this but failed to locate.

Comment: I tried driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Add Criteria')]")).click(); but error stating "element is not clickable at point (some coordinates)"

Comment: So the locator is correct, but you showed incorrect html element to click) 
I can't tell you where you should click if i don't see element on page and it's html

Comment: Yes locator is correct, I don't understand why it is not clicking on the element.is it an issue of firefox? I am using same piece of code if it is identifying the element why dont it is clicking on it?I can provide extra info if required.

Comment: Element is not clickable at point (274.3000030517578, 232.85000610351562) this is the error i am getting

Comment: I have added a new image with bigger DOM structure.Please look into it if it can be of any help.

Comment: probably some element overlaps your "a" element, or "a" element is not actually one that you should click with selenium. Find the real button element, probably user clicks not directly on "a" element, but on it's wrapper